# Logging in no longer works (account does not exist)

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-exchange, login

I have an account at StackOverflow (see https://stackoverflow.com/users/259059/floele).
From there, I can see "network profiles" and see that I also have an account at StackExchange (see https://stackexchange.com/users/95029/floele).

Logging in to StackExchange (and thus also trying to re-login to StackOverflow) does not work however. In my StackOverflow profile, I can clearly see that the e-mail address "floele+stackoverflow@gmail.com" has been used for registration, but this account does not exist on StackExchange (in fact, I created the account just now so that I can post here at all).

So how can I login?

Comment: It says you were seen 18 minutes ago--are you really not able to get in?

Comment: I am still logged in (in Firefox), but I cannot re-login in other browsers currently or be active on a new StackExchange site because I cannot login through StackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged your accounts, so you should be able to sign in with whatever credentials you're using right now and gain access to your Stack Overflow profile.

Enjoy.